# Approx quantile on a array of doubles - Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, quantile

I have a spark dataframe defined as:

```
+----------------+--------------------+-----------+
|        id      |            amt_list|ct_tran_amt|
+----------------+--------------------+-----------+
|1               |[2.99, 7.73, 193....|         23|
|2               |[9.99, 9.95, 5.0,...|         17|
|3               |[4.57, 14.06, 0.7...|         19|
```

How do I calculate approximate quantile (1st and 3rd) as new columns?

`df.stat.approxQuantile("amt",Array(0.25,0.75), 0.001)` does not take a wrapped array as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a built-in spark function to do this, so I would go for an UDF:

```
def calcPercentile(perc:Double) = udf((xs:Seq[Double]) => xs.sorted.apply(((xs.size-1)*perc).toInt))

df
  .withColumn("QT1", calcPercentile(0.25)($"amt_list"))
  .withColumn("QT3", calcPercentile(0.75)($"amt_list"))
  .show()
```

EDIT:

There is also an approach without UDF:

```
df
  .withColumn("Q1", sort_array($"amt_list")(((size($"amt_list")-1)*0.25).cast("int")))
  .withColumn("Q3", sort_array($"amt_list")(((size($"amt_list")-1)*0.75).cast("int")))
  .show()
```

Comment: Also, I figured easier path would to work with individual amounts and perform spark sql. After converting the dataframe to a temp view - use:                                                                                                           val df_t = spark.sql("select id, percentile_approx(amt,0.25) as quantile_1, percentile_approx(amt,0.75) as quantile_3 from df_view group by id")

Comment: @user1124702 I also added an non-UDF solution

Comment: @user1124702 yes this works as an aggregate function, if you already have an column of type array<double> this does not work anymore (unless you explode it first). `percentile_appox` is an hive-built in aggregate function, and rather slow in my experience

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your suggestion Raphael Roth! I will use your withColumn approach.